Surjectivity of kernel operator with kernel in $L^1(\nu \times \mu)$
Let $ \mu $ and $ \nu $ be two finite and non discrete measures. Let's begin with a well-known fact. Let $ k \in L^2(\nu \otimes \mu) $, then we can define an operator $ \tilde{T} $ as follows:
$$
\tilde{T} : L^2(\nu) \to L^2(\mu), \quad g \mapsto \tilde{T} g \text{ such that } \tilde{T} g(x) = \int g(y) k(x, y) \, \nu(dy).
$$
$ \tilde{T} $ is Hilbert-Schmidt and thus compact. Using the property:

Let $E$ and $F$ be two Banach spaces. Let $L$ be a compact operator. If $F$ is not finite-dimensional, then $L$ is not surjective,

we conclude that $ \tilde{T} $ is not surjective since $ \mu $ does not have a finite support.
Here is my question: if we now define $T$ in $L^1(\nu \times \mu)$:
$$
T : L^1(\nu) \to L^1(\mu), \quad g \mapsto T g \text{ such that } T g(x) = \int g(y) k(x, y) \, \nu(dy),
$$
We suppose $T$ bounded.
I am asking whether $T$ can be surjective. The answer is less obvious since $T$ is not always compact: using Dunford-Pettis theorem, one shows that $T$ is weakly compact if and only if the family $(k(., y))_y$ is uniformly integrable with respect to $ \mu $.

You need the stronger assumption $\sup_x \int |K(x,y)|, dy \leq C$ for $T$ to be bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$.

@GiorgioMetafune Yes, sorry I forgot to say that T is supposed bounded.
